# php: select* from table

Tags: php, oracle

> oci_execute(): ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C0010278) violated in E:\Xamp\htdocs\show.php on line 10

when I am checking sql plus using select* there is no row selected

```
<?php // File: anyco.php
    require('anyco_ui.inc.php');
    // Create a database connection
    $conn = oci_connect('system','123','localhost/orcl');
    ui_print_header('Employees');

    $q= "insert into Employee values(1005099,'NawSafrin','Sattar','female','Mohammadpur',01520100508,'Senior',15000,'8 AM-5 PM','1-Jan-2011')";

    $s = oci_parse($conn,$q);
    $r1= oci_execute($s,OCI_DEFAULT);
    do_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Employee");
    ui_print_footer(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    // Execute query and display results
function do_query($conn, $query)
{
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
    print '<table border="1">';
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>Employee ID<td>Employee Fname<td>Employee Lname<td>gender<td>address<td>phn_Number<td>category<td>salary<td>work_hr<td>join_date';
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
    {
        print '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $item) 
        {
            print '<td>'.
            ($item!== null ? htmlentities($item) : '&nbsp;').'</td>';
        }
        print '</tr>';
    }
    print '</table>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: please refer this page.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql syntax here is incorrect:

```
$q= "insert into Employee values(1005099,'NawSafrin','Sattar','female','Mohammadpur',01520100508,'Senior',15000,'8 AM-5 PM','1-Jan-2011')";
```

Must be:

```
$q= "insert into Employee('name of all columns you like to be inserted') values(1005099,'NawSafrin','Sattar','female','Mohammadpur',01520100508,'Senior',15000,'8 AM-5 PM','1-Jan-2011')";
```

Comment: but its not working for do_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Employee"); statement......its not showing all the tuples already inserted in the Employee table

Comment: did you already check your databases? does the data you inserted already there?

Comment: yes the data are inserted  oci_execute(): ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C0010398) violated in E:\Xamp\htdocs\show.php on line 9 is the error

Comment: :) now the data are shown but the warning is also showing Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C0010398) violated in E:\Xamp\htdocs\show.php on line 9

Comment: there is duplication of your unique data, for example, if you have "1005099"  as your ID, and ID was your primary key for that table then  you add another same data, that error will probably occur.